# Browser rendering and streaming

Tags: java, firefox, opengl, rendering

I want to to render an application (e.g. a browser) in memory (not on screen) and stream the result of this rendering to a couple of remote desktops.

What options do I have? Is there a Java framework (maybe based on OpenGL) that I can use for this?

Comment: something along the lines of teamviewer? or do i misunderstand?

Comment: The difference being that teamviewer is capturing one screen and replicating it to other screens. What I want is capture something that is in memory and not necessarily in screen. There is a discussion here http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showthreaded&Number=71344   that shows how this would be done in OpenGL. I will need to see if I can use JOGL to do the same.

Comment: java will not allow you to access areas of memory that reside outside of your current java process.

Comment: The thread on opengl.org you linked deals with a very specific case, namely a PBuffer. That is a offscreen buffer, created by the application in question to specifically support OpenGL. You can not use a PBuffer to redirect other applications there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenGL is a drawing API; totally unsuited for your demands; just telling you to clear things up.

The whole "do the thing off-screen" requires to hook into the lower parts of the graphics system. With Java this means serious tinkering with the JNI and probably also some native binary code. IMHO not worth the effort, as there is a much nicer solution:

Xorg has a X server that is backed by a VNC framebuffer (*Xvnc*). You can start a browser in such and if there's no window manager and desktop environment running, the browser will be the only thing visible, no decorations, titlebar or the like. Then you connect using VNC to that server and will see the picture of the browser only. Technically VNC is just a video stream of JPEG images, and there are tools to create a regular video stream from VNC.

X provides you an additional possibility: The **Composite** extension. X Composite provides a mechanism to transfer a window into an offscreen rendering area. The contents rendered to the offscreen area must be composited to the screen by a so called *compositor*. It is possible, though quite inefficient, to copy those offscreen images into process memory and from there build a video stream.

Comment: Thanks, not what I was expecting but a pretty knowledgeable answer.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are trying to do, you could run you application on a linux box and stream the output of the application over SSH to an xserver on another machine. I believe that there are xservers available for Windows and MacOS, but this gets you pretty far away from Java.

http://www.vanemery.com/Linux/XoverSSH/X-over-SSH2.html